# CSS - Sub menu is not visible

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/4hLnZ/

can someone figure out why my sub menus are not displaying above the content div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it helps to write out the selector completely, especially for menu items.

Set your menu as a block item, this way it behaves like a div. The list items can be inline-block (horizontal menu) or block (vertical menu).

The :hover effect can be achieved by an overwrite.
Giving extra weight in the li:hover selector (careful, CSS3 only):

```
#menu ul li ul { display:none; }
#menu ul li:hover ul { display:block; }
```

Better CSS should be

```
#menu { height: 30px; }
#menu ul { display: block; position: relative; z-index: 100; }
#menu ul li { float: left; list-style: none; margin: 0; padding:0; }
#menu ul li ul { display:none; }
#menu ul li a { width:100px; height: 30px; display: block; text-decoration:none; text-align: center; line-height: 30px; background-color: black; color: white; }
#menu ul li a:hover { background-color: red; }
#menu ul li:hover ul { position: absolute; top: 30px; display: block; width: 100px; }
#menu ul li:hover ul li { display:block; }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tive/4hLnZ/6/

Answer (score 1):

The reason for submenu not showing is that content is over it, because it is defined later.

Add this:

```
#menu li {
  ...
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: I changed, but still the issue exist.

Comment: got it.. changed #menu li {... z-index:100;}

Comment: sorry, I guess I wasn't clear enough. I'm glad you figured it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

Define `z-index` on `#menu` with `position:relative`.

like this:

```
 #menu{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 position:relative;
 z-index:100;
 }
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/4hLnZ/4/

Answer (score 0):

Use this

`#menu ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    visibility: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
}`

Add `z-index: 1;` for #menu ul ul